# How can I send special character parameter in URLencoded form without change using volley library

Tags: android, android-volley, special-characters, url-encoding

How can I send special character parameter in URLencoded form without change using volley library

I have to send 
qty$1:23
qty$2:666
this data in URLencoded form using volley library but due to Volley Request class it is doing UTF encoding foe key value pairs.How can I avoid to change the parameter names.

Using Volley now parameters names are changed like qty%241:23 which is not acceptable by server.Please help me

Comment: Please post the code that you are using

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding first:

`String encoded = URLEncoder.encode(stringToEncode, "UTF-8");` and send the encoded string.

According to the documentation of this method:

> This method uses the supplied encoding scheme to obtain the bytes for unsafe characters.

Comment: after this encoding parametername is changed to qty%241 after this pass in volley with URLencoded content type again encodes the parameters and finally parameter name is changed before service call